# How to initialize a generic element to an arbitrary value?

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code with the structure

```
template <typename T>
{ 
    // ...
    T t;
    if (foo(t)) // foo is of the form bool foo(T &)
    {
       // ...
    }
    // ....
}
```

and Visual Studio is angry because it thinks `t` needs to be initialized for the function `foo` to work (which isn't true). Is there some way I can initialize a generic element?

Comment: This is a *function* template, right?

Comment: It looks like a block template -.-

Answer (score 1):

You can write `T t{};` in C++11.

Comment: Or `T t = T();` in pre `C++11`